# Making new column for bins works, but gives only one bin in all rows

Tags: python, pandas, bin

I'm going crazy here, because whatever I do, I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Problem:

I have a df. One of the columns is: Opnameduur. This is type int64.

My def creates a new columns named: Klasse. This works oke. But....
Based on value found in column df.Opnameduur, the function is supposed to write a bin (dag, kort, middel, long (witch is Dutch for day, short, middle, long) in the corresponding row in the new column df.Klasse.

The column is created, df.Klasse, but ALL values in the df.KLasse are set to: dag.

I just can't understand what's wrong here....

```
df.Opnameduur.head()
```

gives:

```
0    1
1    1
2    9
3    1
4    3
```

So, first two rows should give: dag, in df.Klasse, third row should give: long. etc.

But, my def sets 'dag' in the entire new column df.Klasse.

I feel pretty stupid not seeing it myself. So.. I need your help! This is my function:

```
def Klasse(df):
    for index, value in df.Opnameduur.items():
        if value == 1:
            df['Klasse'] = 'dag'
        elif value == 2:
            df['Klasse'] = 'kort'
        elif value == 3:
            df['Klasse'] = 'kort'
        elif value == 4:
            df['Klasse'] = 'middel'
        elif value == 5:
            df['Klasse'] = 'middel'
        elif value == 6:
            df['Klasse'] = 'middel'
        elif value >= 7:
            df['Klasse'] = 'lang'
        else:
            df['Klasse'] = 'onbekend'
```

I've read about pandas.cut now, but before diving into that I want to understand my mistake here with the (supposed to be...) pretty straightforware if, elif, else.

Thanks in advance!!! greetings Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While doing `df['Klasse'] == 'value'` , the `value` is assigned to the whole column since assignment is a vectorized operation. You can use the `loc` method of dataframe in pandas and pass the correct index names of rows and columns, for reassignment of values,like this:

```
def Klasse(df):
    for index, value in df.Opnameduur.items():
        if value == 1:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'dag'
        elif value == 2:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'kort'
        elif value == 3:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'kort'
        elif value == 4:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'middel'
        elif value == 5:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'middel'
        elif value == 6:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'middel'
        elif value >= 7:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'lang'
        else:
            df.loc[index, 'Klasse'] = 'onbekend'
```

Comment: Anup thanks!! This works perfect. And great to learn about the vectorized operation. Never too old to learn! (I'm 58, enthousiastic studying Python and Pandas, but learning something new isn't as easy anymore as like being 20 or so. Thanks again Anup!! greetings Jan (From The Netherlands).